# List longitude and latitude pairs in a netCDF file

Tags: coordinates, netcdf, value-list

Is there a command line tool/solution (like `cdo` or `nco` or `gdal` or `rio`) to list/print the pairs of (`longitude`, `latitude`) values in a netCDF file (yet not one of: [netcdf4-python](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/), [rio](https://github.com/leeper/rio), [xarray](https://xarray.dev/), [rioxarray](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/), [geopandas](https://geopandas.org) or [GRASS GIS' r.stats](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/r.stats.html) or any other scripting effort)?

Comment: I'd try ncdump, which comes when netcfd4-python is installed.  See:  https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/workshops/2011/utilities/Ncdump.html

Comment: This `ncdump sample.nc -v longitude | sed -e '1,/data:/d' -e '$d'` will do, though the output still needs some post-processing. See also: [Re: \[netcdfgroup\] ncdump with just the variable's values?](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/mailing_lists/archives/netcdfgroup/2011/msg00317.html).